# How to know whether realm.commitTransaction() succefull

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In my application I'm inserting user like below

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I want to display and message if data inserted correctly. How to check if data insertion works successfully or not.

I know if I use `realm.executeTransactionAsync()` method I can get callback for `onSuccess()` and `onError()`. But It does not make any sense to insert one object asynchronously just to get access in to `onSuccess()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);` will return an object of type user which is managed by realm signifying that it got inserted. If that object is null that would imply that the transaction did not succeed in which case it would have crashed with an exception.